# C# Console application two main()

Tags: c#, console-application

I have my Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
     static void Main()
    {
   // code here
    }
 }
```

and then I add a Class File, that looks like this:

```
using here;

public class AddItem
{

}
```

and everything I write inside becomes red underlined. I tried adding a static void Main(), which removed the underlines, but I can't start it because of more than one entry point defined.

I rarely do console applications, in Windows Forms applications I just add it and it works right away - why doesn't it work in console applications?

most errors are "Invlaid token = in class, struct, or interface member declaration."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftiAO.png

Comment: You're saying _"everything I write inside becomes red underlined"._ It would be (have been) useful to see an example of what you've been writing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your image is accurate, you do not have a method.  You are writing code directly into the class definition.

You need something more like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't belive I missed that! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nicole DesRosiers Good one, I did not see the screenshot :)